# Accessing data MySQL. Freezing on build

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, gradle, compiler-errors

I am currently following along with this document:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

and when I build using Gradle, the process does not finish executing.

```
20-10-11 18:12:09.099  INFO 4584 --- [task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-10-11 18:12:09.245  INFO 4584 --- [main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-10-11 18:12:09.253  INFO 4584 --- [main] c.e.a.AccessingDataMysqlApplication      : Started AccessingDataMysqlApplication in 4.295 seconds (JVM running for 4.699)
<=========----> 75% EXECUTING [4m 32s]
```

I am new to Spring and starting a project from the ground up and do not know where to begin looking to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are not just building the application - you are actually running it. And since it is a web application, listening to web requests on `localhost:8080/demo`, it runs until you exit it with ctrl+c.